# Severity and priority rank of Insecure Direct Object Reference bug

Tags: authentication, web-application, vulnerability, access-control, disclosure

Recently, I found bug in an e-commerce web app and I will  report it.

The bug I found can:

- delete and edit the favorite products list for all users
- delete all notifications for all users

What severity and priority of this vulnerability can I report?

Comment: Well, that certainly sounds pretty severe, but ultimately that is for them to decide, not you.  You could take a shot at assigning it a CVSS score that they can then choose to either accept or not.

Comment: If they refuse to accept it, a great place to disclose it so the public can be aware is [seclists](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/). If the web app is popular and not some bespoke product for this one company, you could also [request a CVE](https://cveform.mitre.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually say that sounds only moderately *severe*, because the direct harm that can be done is pretty minor. An attacker can breach a degree of confidentiality (information disclosure), can inconvenience people, can potentially deceive people, and can definitely damage the company's reputation, but can't directly cause much harm (e.g. force people to buy things, access information useful for identity theft, take over user accounts, or gain unauthorized access to the server).

I'd call it a pretty high *priority*, though. Direct object references are relatively easy to discover and usually also easy to exploit (i.e. usually it's just an integer you can iterate through), and the exploit can generally be scaled easily to affect a large number of people (they tend to be very amenable to automation and not require any interaction on anybody else's part). Ease of discovery and exploitation usually raise the priority, even when the severity is only middling.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a very high priority. An attacker could advertise his/her product by putting it on other users' favorites list, for example.

As mentioned by @xander, it's up to the company regarding whether or not they'll fix it, but I recommend submitting as a high priority so that they can be aware.